# How do you open a downloaded file from synaptic?

Tags: synaptic

I am trying to open a file I downloaded from Synaptic. How do you do that?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Why do you need synaptic, specifically? To download a package, one simply types `apt-get download packagename` in a terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the packages you are downloading through the synaptic package manager will be at `/var/cache/apt/archives` location in your PC.Those packages will be in .DEB format.

so if you like to open the .DEB file , you can do it with

```
ar vx your_package.deb.
```

Comment: @user157447 hi , tell us what exactly you want so that we can help you.

Comment: Hello, still having trouble. I can download the packages from synaptic, but I cannot open them to configure the settings. For example, I installed a synthesizer for MIDI but I don't know how to open the program and use it.

Comment: what ever the program you have downloaded from the synaptic that will be installed automatically , you no need to install it manually.

Comment: Yes but how do you open the program that you installed?

Comment: open unity dash and type there the program what you would like to launch.

Comment: @user157447 this is the unity dash , type here the the application name you want http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/old-school-dash-poc-screenshot.png

Answer (score 0):

Once the downloads are finished, go in *Synaptic Package Manager* again and select the same package(s) name(s) that you initially selected. Go to “*Add downloaded packages*” from the *File* menu, notice that the window that pops up is titled "*Select directory*" not "*Select file(s)*", you do not select individual package files but the directory which contains them. Therefore you should browse to the directory which contains `'Downloads'`, click once on `'Downloads'` to select it, then click *Open*. Synaptic will then scan the selected directory for packages and offer to install them.

It is really quite simple to use: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Synaptic/PackageDownloadScript